# If Dictionary is implemented using AVL tree or Red-Black tree, how is the time complexity O(1)?

Tags: dictionary, hash, tree

While studying Balanced BST, I heard that Dictionary can be implemented using AVL tree or Red-Black tree.

Those two trees have time complexity of O(logN) for search, insertion and deletion.
Then, isn't the time complexity of dictionary supposed to be O(logN), not O(1)? (If it was implemented using tree)

I know why hash tables can be described as O(1) even with the worst time complexity of O(n) since we talk about the average case. However, balanced BST's average time complexity is O(logN).

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why do you ask? Did you have a source that contradicts this? Who says that a dictionary that is implemented with sef-balancing BST has a time complexity of O(1) for its operations?

Comment: Isn't dictionary always represented as having time complexity of O(1) in any languages? I don't know a specific language that uses self-balancing BST for dictionary, but I thought it has O(1) time compexity regardless of the implementations. If I were wrong, please correct me

Comment: *"I don't know a specific language that uses self-balancing BST for dictionary"*: that's your answer. You are conflating two things that don't occur together. Self-balancing trees on the one hand and dictionaries with O(1) operations on the other hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to differentiate between the abstract data type called Dictionary, and the different data structures you can use to *implement* the Dictionary's functions.

"Dictionary" is an abstract data type that defines *insert*, *remove*, and *lookup* operations. Nothing in the definition of the data type says anything about the implementation or makes any guarantees about the time complexity. If an implementation provides the required functionality (*insert*, *remove*, *lookup*), then it's a Dictionary.

You can implement a Dictionary with a linked list or an array, if you like. It will be slow (O(n) access), but it satisfies the definition of a Dictionary. Or you could implement it with a balanced binary tree, a skip list, an SQL database, a hash table, a trie, and likely a number of other data structures. All of those implementations would perform the functions of a Dictionary, but with varying efficiency.